# Add Update And Delete Button In Retrieved Data From SQL Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

I am retrieving data from SQL using PHP on a page and showing many records at a time using below code.

```
<?php
//Database Connection File
require_once("config.php");
//Everything Is Okay So Let's Garb This User Contacts Data
$garb = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE A_Id = '$A_Id'");
if(!$garb){
$error = "<div class='error'>There's Little Problem: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
} else {
//Data Is Collected
    //Showing The User Data
    $idNo = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($garb)) {                   
    $C_FullName = $row['C_FullName'];
    $C_Gender = $row['C_Gender'];
    $C_ContactPhone = $row['C_ContactPhone'];
    $C_ContactCell = $row['C_ContactCell'];
    $C_Email = $row['C_Email'];
    $C_Address = $row['C_Address'];
    $C_Group = $row['C_Group'];
    $C_Notes = $row['C_Notes'];
    echo '
    <div class="accordionItem close">
    <h3 class="accordionItemHeading">'.$C_FullName.'</h3>
    <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <div id="contactDetailes">
            <form id="updateAllContact'.$idNo.'" method="post" action="">
                <p><label>Full Name:* </label><input type="text" name="C_FullName" value="'.$C_FullName.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Gender:* </label><input type="text" name="C_Gender" value="'.$C_Gender.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Contact No(Phone): </label><input type="text" name="C_ContactPhone" value="'.$C_ContactPhone.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Contact No(Cell): </label><input type="text" name="C_ContactCell" value="'.$C_ContactCell.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Email Address:* </label><input type="text" name="C_Email" value="'.$C_Email.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Address: </label><input type="text" name="C_Address" value="'.$C_Address.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Group: </label><input type="text" name="C_Group" value="'.$C_Group.'"></input></p>
                <p><label>Notes: </label><textarea type="text" name="C_Notes">'.$C_Notes.'</textarea></p>
                <span>
                <a class="updateButton">Update</a>
                <a class="deleteButton">Delete</a>
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
    $idNo++;
    }
}
?>
```

Now the problem is that I want to add `Update` and `Delete` function for every row retrieved from database. What I want is something like [HTML5 Web SQL Databases And Usage](http://www.exeideas.com/2016/03/html5-web-sql-databases.html) or something like [HTML5 Address Book](http://exeideaslab.blogspot.com/2016/02/html5-web-sql.html) using PHP and SQL. So how can I add functions of  `Update` and `Delete` in my every row data...???

Comment: Is this more of a front-end(JS) question? If so, take a look at ajax

Comment: Here is a good place to start: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/05/crud-with-php-jquery.html

Comment: If you are going to use javascript, you will want to not use `id` in your loop, or if you do, append with a number. Ids are meant to be unique.

Comment: @Rasclatt I added `id="updateAllContact'.$idNo.'"` that means to be unique... Is not it?

Comment: Yes, that would be unique then, now it's a bit more in line with unique id conventions and won't confuse any javascript(s) that reference id's inside that loop.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I will follow this rule also...